# IntelliJ Tomcat serves wrong webapp

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate to develop a SpringBoot App (+ maven). When i hit run, tomcat still serves a old vaadin project. How can i remove it? I already cleared my browsers cache, tried to load the side in a private browser window and removed the project from the tomcats webapp folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try these things:

1. Change the port number in the ***application.properties*** file.

   > server.port = [port number]

[image]

2. Edit the project's configuration and explicitly add the ***@SpringBootApplication*** containing class or just go to the file and run the **main()** method.

[image]

Comment: Still seeing my old vaadin project

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the project's JAR or WAR file; don't forget to delete the folder from server and the restart the server. i hope this should help!

Comment: How do i access the server i started with intellij? The webapp folder i mentioned seems to be the wrong one

Answer (score 0):

Few things can be checked.

1. If you are using your local tomcat then verify the tomcat if that is the one you are actually using. Better remove the tomcat and import a fresh one.

or

1. close the project from IntelliJ and reimport.
2. clean build maven project and run again.